# Eclipse java package structure with linked resource folder

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, package

I've a project with some java source file and a structure like this:

### -projects

### --project1

---utils
---servlets
---calls
---listeners (same level)

Every folder in project1 contains .java source that have the same build package, for example it.test.project1 .

I've try to define a project in eclipse, in another dir, with one linked folder to project1 or multiple linked folder to utils,servlets...but when i build it, the .class files are generated in the build folder (...\classes) without package.

If i define a package it.test.project1 each subfolder is generated inside the package or without the package(only name of subfolder in build folder)...

Is there a way to get a final package it.test.project1 that contains all .class, without subfolder, from original multi folder with different structure?

I can't change my original structure.

Comment: Could you please explain why you cannot change your original structure? This looks like a situation where these things should be in a common source folder with different packages. Or different projects that depend on one another or both.

Comment: I'can't change the original structure of project because it's stored in a svn repository and there is a lot difficult, work to do and risk with a change on this structure.

Comment: Now we work with Jcreator and we have this structure in each worspace/project (one worspace for one customer/product, each workspace contains 1,2 or 3 project >>> "common source project", "core source project", "custom source project"), the build setting in Jcreator IDE allows me to generate the .class file outside the project, in tomcat/webapp/web-inf/classes/pkg dir, and there is no declaration of package in IDE, only in the source file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jcreator.  It seems that you have built your whole environment around some idiosyncrasy of the tool which is not ideal. Ideally a developer should be able to use whatever IDE they like and are familiar with if they have a license for it. I would suggest that your whole development approach could do with some reconsideration.   Moving files in a SVN repository is not the end of the world but it seems there are some limitations your organization has imposed that could make satisfactory resolution of the problem difficult.

Comment: The are many sources in each subfolder, it's difficult to maintain about 1000 files in the same folder, when we create the .ear with an ant script, we do the union in the same folder/package, but only when we release a new version of the product for the customer, not for development.

Comment: I have worked with eclipse, netbeans, and Jdeveloper.  All of these allow a folder structure that reflects the package structure. These folders exist within a single  or multple source folders. And usually compile into a single class folder With a parallel folder structure.  And having 1000 classes in a single package would be wrong. Maybe I am not understanding the structure how actually have but it seems that you do not have folders that reflect your package

Comment: the structure is organaized to have a single package for each product, may be is not the best solution, but there is a workaround to do it possibile in eclipse?

Comment: I am not at a computer at the moment (using a tablet) but I think eclipse can produce different target folders from source folders. eclipse will expect  the path from the source folder to the java files match the package name.